# how to sum datatables in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

the result just show
`$NaN ( $NaN total)`

I just copying code from [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) and I just change the column where I wanna SUM it.
here my code before

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tableoperasional').DataTable( {
  "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
     var api = this.api(), data;
                             
     // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
     var intVal = function ( i ) {
       return typeof i === 'string' 
         ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1
         : typeof i === 'number'
         ? i 
         : 0;
     };

    // Total over all pages
    total = api
      .column( 2 )
      .data()
      .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0 );
                             
      // Total over this page
      pageTotal = api
        .column( 2, { page: 'current'} )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0 );
                             
        // Update footer
        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 2 ).footer() ).html(
          '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
        );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I also updated the js lib, and still nothing happened. I hope your help.

Comment: Added relevant javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables tags; formatted code to be readable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean :( . I'm new in JS btw .

Comment: That comment was added because I edited the question ;-) Look below for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Main problem**

I think the problem lies within your `intVal` function. When a `String` is passed into it, all `$` and `,` chars are removed and the result is multiplied by `1` (which converts it into a `Number`). However, if `String.prototype.replace` does not remove all non-numeric characters, that conversion will fail and `NaN` is returned.

For example:

```
var valueInColumn = '12,45%';
var nanResult = valueInColumn.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1;
console.log(nanResult);
```

Instead of using implicit conversion (`* 1`), use explicit conversion via `parseFloat`/`parseInt`. It's clearer about the intention and also a bit safer than implicit conversion:

```
var intVal = function (i) {
  return typeof i === 'string'
    ? parseFloat(i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')) // <-- here
    : typeof i === 'number'
    ? i
    : 0;
}
```

In case this does not solve the problem, `intVal` can be made safer/more strict. Here's how:

```
var safeIntVal = i => {
  var rval = i;
  if (typeof rval === 'string') {
    rval = parseFloat(rval.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));    // <-- remove all non-numeric characters except dots and convert into a number
  }
  if (typeof rval !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(rval)) { // <-- if the result of the conversion isn't a number or is NaN, set it to zero
    rval = 0;
  }
  return rval;                                          // <-- return
}
```

The difference in both implementations becomes visible in the following snippet:

```js
var intVal = function ( i ) {
  return typeof i === 'string' 
    ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1
    : typeof i === 'number'
    ? i 
    : 0;
};

var safeIntVal = function (i) {
  var rval = i;
  if (typeof rval === 'string') {
    rval = parseFloat(rval.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
  }
  if (typeof rval !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(rval)) {
    rval = 0;
  }
  return rval;
}



var testString = 'a23,3.65$b';

console.log('Original intVal result:', intVal(testString));
console.log('Modified safeIntVal result:', safeIntVal(testString));
```

**Side notes**

You declare a `data` variable inside the `footerCallback` function that shadows the equally named argument that's passed to the callback. Also, the `total` and `pageTotal` variables look like implicit global variables (they are declared without the `var` keyword).